# How to get maximum time value of the current date in miliseconds in Java?

Tags: java, date, time

How to get maximum time value of the current date in miliseconds in Java ?
E.g. 18th July 23.59 in epoch miliseconds where current time would be anything of 18th July

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There’s room for a bit of interpretation in your question. I suggest:

```
    ZoneId zone = ZoneId.systemDefault();
    long endOfDay = LocalDate.now(zone)
            .plusDays(1)
            .atStartOfDay(zone)
            .toInstant()
            .minusMillis(1)
            .toEpochMilli();
    System.out.println(endOfDay);
```

On my computer it just printed

```
1500501599999
```

This corresponds to a `ZonedDateTime` of 2017-07-19T23:59:59.999+02:00[Europe/Berlin].

Please note that the end of the day is time zone dependent, so you need to decide a time zone for the operation. Please fill in your desired time zone instead of `ZoneId.systemDefault()`.

Since Java doesn’t include an “end of the day” operation I opted for adding one day, taking the beginning of the day in the time zone in question and then subtracting 1 millisecond (because you asked for milliseconds since the epoch). If you want, you may instead subtract a nanosecond, a second or a minute, for example. If you want to subtract a whole minute, the simplest is to use `.minusMinutes(1)` before `toInstant()`.

The code should be safe even on a day and in a time zone where a summer time transition (DST changeover) happens at midnight.

Answer (score 3):

## Half-Open

Seems like your Question involves determining the last moment of the day. Such a goal is ill-advised.

The last moment of the day is infinitely divisible as a fraction of a second, such as 2017-01-23T23:59:59.999Z. But different software uses different granularities when resolving such date-time values. The old legacy date-time classes is Java use milliseconds, or 3 decimal places. The new java.time classes use nanoseconds, or 9 decimal places. Other software such as the Postgres database use microseconds, for 6 decimal places. Other software uses other resolutions such as 5 decimal places. So you will be getting different values in different scenarios for the same date.

A better approach to defining spans of time is commonly used in date-time work, and avoids this ambiguity of last-moment-of-the-day: Half-Open. In this approach the beginning is *inclusive* while the ending is *exclusive*. So a single full day starts at the first moment of one date and runs up to, but does *not* include, the **first moment of the following day**. For UTC, that would be `2017-01-23T00:00:00Z` to `2017-01-24T00:00:00Z`.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ; 
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z ) ;
ZonedDateTime todayStart = today.atStartOfDay( z ) ;

long secondsSinceEpoch = todayStart.toEpochSecond() ;  // Whole seconds since epoch of 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z.
long millisecondsSinceEpoch = todayStart.toInstant().toEpochMilli() ;  // Milliseconds since epoch of 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z.
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](http://ideone.com/XCV7Re).

> todayStart: 2017-07-19T00:00-04:00[America/Montreal]
>
> millisecondsSinceEpoch: 1500436800000

For the following day (tomorrow), add one day to the `LocalDate`.

```
LocalDate tomorrow = today.plusDays( 1 ) ;
ZonedDateTime tomorrowStart = tomorrow.atStartOfDay( z ) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure how the specific date plays into this, but if you want to find the last millisecond of the day, I would use `LocalTime.MAX.toNanoOfDay()/1000000`. This takes the maximum nanosecond of the day, then divides by 1000000 to convert to milliseconds. If you wanted to combine this with a date, I would combine this value with a LocalDate or LocalDateTime value.